# While loop exits after reading one line using ssh

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Hi I have file name bonding with below entry:

```
testnode1 eth0
tetnode2  eth2
```

Now I'm writing a bash script  do a loop using while to put that entry in to variable then use it to below command:

```
ssh $serv ifconfig | grep $nic
```

Problem is its exited to early after the first read " testnode1 " it does not execute the next line " testnod2"

Here is the whole code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat bonding | while read line
do
    serv=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    nic=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    echo $serv
    ssh $serv ifconfig | grep $nic
done
```

output:

```
testnode1
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:99:C0:CD
```

expected output

```
testnode1
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:99:C0:CD  
testnode2
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0A:30:40:QB:A1
```

Can someone point me to my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `ssh` reads from stdin. Since you are looping to read from a file, `ssh` reads everything and in the next iteration, there's nothing more to read. Hence, the loop exits after one iteration.

You can do:

```
ssh "$serv ifconfig | grep $nic" </dev/null
```

or

```
ssh -n $serv ifconfig | grep $nic
```

From the `ssh` manual:

> ```
>  -n
> ```
>
> Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh is run in the
>   background.  A common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a
>   remote machine.  For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will
>   start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be
>   automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program
>   will be put in the background.  (This does not work if ssh needs to
>   ask for a password or passphrase; see also the -f option.)